# DateTimeOffset throw exception in moq setup

Tags: c#, moq, xunit

I have a method with logger:

```
this.logger.LogDebug("Engine start run at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
this.logger.LogDebug("Engine stopped at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
```

I created a UT with moq setup to check this case:

```
var firstMessageStartLoggingTime = $"Engine start run at: {DateTimeOffset.Now}";
var secondMessageStoppedLoggingTime = $"Engine stopped at: {DateTimeOffset.Now}";

_mockLogger.Setup(e => e.LogDebug(firstMessageStartLoggingTime)).Verifiable(); 
_mockLogger.Setup(e => e.LogDebug(secondMessageStoppedLoggingTime)).Verifiable();
```

And received this exception:

```
Message: 
Moq.MockException : Mock<ILoggerAdapter<Engine>:1>:
This mock failed verification due to the following:

   ILoggerAdapter<Engine> e => e.LogDebug("Engine start run at: 6/4/2021 8:52:16 AM +03:00", []):
   This setup was not matched.

   ILoggerAdapter<Engine> e => e.LogDebug("Engine stopped at: 6/4/2021 8:52:16 AM +03:00", []):
   This setup was not matched.
```

Then I tried to update this case by adding DateTimeProvider class:

```
public class DateTimeProvider
{
    public static DateTime Today
    {
        get
        {
            if (!TodayValue.HasValue)
            {
                return DateTime.Today;
            }
            else
            {
                return TodayValue.Value;
            }
        }
    }

    public static DateTime Now
    {
        get
        {
            if (!NowValue.HasValue)
            {
                return DateTime.Now;
            }
            else
            {
                return NowValue.Value;
            }
        }
    }

    public static DateTime UtcNow
    {
        get
        {
            if (!UtcNowValue.HasValue)
            {
                return DateTime.UtcNow;
            }
            else
            {
                return UtcNowValue.Value;
            }
        }
    }

    internal static DateTime? TodayValue { get; set; }

    internal static DateTime? NowValue { get; set; }

    internal static DateTime? UtcNowValue { get; set; }
```

And updated this method with it (code in method):

```
this.logger.LogDebug("Engine start run at: {time}", DateTimeOffsetProvider.Now);
this.logger.LogDebug("Engine stopped at: {time}", DateTimeOffsetProvider.Now);
```

And updated UT:

```
DateTime expected = DateTime.Now;
DateTimeProvider.TodayValue = expected;
var firstMessageStartLoggingTime = $"Engine start run at: {expected}";
var secondMessageStoppedLoggingTime = $"Engine stopped at: {expected}";

_mockLogger.Setup(e => e.LogDebug(firstMessageStartLoggingTime)).Verifiable(); 
_mockLogger.Setup(e => e.LogDebug(secondMessageStoppedLoggingTime)).Verifiable();
```

But the error still remains.
Please, help :)

Comment: `DateTimeOffset.Now` has different value when it is evaluated in test code and in the real code after a few miliseconds. That's why the verification fails. You might want to ignore the value being passed to the LogDebug method when you do setup... `_mockLogger.Setup(e => e.LogDebug(It.IsAny<string>())).Verifiable()`

Comment: Or you can put a constraint for argument matching... `_mockLogger.Setup(e => e.LogDebug(It.Is<string>(s => s.StartsWith("Engine start run at:")))).Verifiable()` and `_mockLogger.Setup(e => e.LogDebug(It.Is<string>(s => s.StartsWith("Engine stopped at:")))).Verifiable()`

Comment: As @ChetanRanpariya has suggested `It.Is` can be useful to check the log message. You can also use that to verify the format of the datetime. Or you can go even further and assess that the parsed datetime is not lower or greater than a given delta (for example: +- 10seconds).

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya and @Peter Csala, but if I have 3 loggers messages two of these cases and one cases to check another log message. When I tried to comment these two lines of logger test passes (1 left only one check) and code coverage marks all logger (these 3 lines) as green. When I try to add your`s examples test doesn`t pass with the same message.

Comment: What's the second argument `[]` in LogDebug method?

Comment: Setup was not matched because you forgot to setup in `LogDebug` the params object[], the second argument you are passing, which is actually the DateTimeOffset. `_mockLogger.Setup(e => e.LogDebug(firstMessageStartLoggingTime, It.IsAny<object[]>())`

Comment: What logger are you using? MS logging `ILogger<T>`? What version of .NET? I ask as at least up to .NET 3.x `LogDebug` is an extension method.